Where should I write my Validators in Angular 17?
I am using Angular 17, and I need to write some custom validators for my reactive typed forms. I was going to write them in the component where my form is declared, but I know these validators are going to be reused on different forms across the application.
I am contemplating creating a ValidatorService where all my custom Validators would be stored, but I am wondering wha the best practice should be? Should I have an utils class instead maybe?

I recommend the developer guides from angular.io that explain what a custom validator is. It's just a function, you can put each validator in its own file, in your shared folder and be done with it.

I personally prefer organizing custom validators in a dedicated validators folder, with each validator in its own file. This structure makes it easier to manage, track, and reuse validators across the application. Here’s an example of how you can set this up:
Folder Structure
validators/
├── payment-period.validator.ts
├── customer-id.validator.ts
├── delivery-date.validator.ts
└── index.ts

Example Validator File: delivery-date.validator.ts
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function validateDeliveryDate(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    // Your validation logic here
    const isValid = /* your validation logic */;
    return isValid ? null : { deliveryDate: true };
  };
}

index.ts File
// Export all validators from this file for easy import elsewhere
export * from './payment-period.validator';
export * from './customer-id.validator';
export * from './delivery-date.validator';

Usage in a Component
By organizing your validators this way, you can easily import them into any component or service:
import { validateDeliveryDate, validateCustomerId } from '../validators';

@Component({
  // Component metadata
})
export class MyComponent {
  form = this.fb.group({
    deliveryDate: ['', [validateDeliveryDate()]],
    customerId: ['', [validateCustomerId()]],
    // Other form controls
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
}

This approach keeps your code organized, makes validators easily reusable, and simplifies the maintenance and tracking of validators throughout your application.

I wouldn´t recommend using a barrel file (index.ts) for this. You can safely import from each file separately. All other suggestions are valid and best practise.

Thank you, I went with this approach and I am happy with it :)

You needn't create a service
You can create a .ts with your functions
export function validator1(...){...}
export function validator2(...){...}

Or create an object
export CustomValidators{
     validator1:(...)=>{...}
     validator2:(...)=>{...}
}

then import them in the .ts where are necesary
import {validator1,validator2} from '../../my-functions.ts'

or

import {CustomValidators} form './my-object-validator.ts'


Thank you! I was also considering a CustomValidators class, but I think I will go with one file per custom validator as per suggested above. Thank you for your reply!
